# app.yaml Script handlers and Static file handlers

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a folder structure (see image) and My app.yaml is shown below. My site runs but my PHP files are not executing. I keep trying (mostly by looking at [google help](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Script_handlers) page) to figure out how I can make all php files in my php folder execute. Not all files in my PHP folder should execute just the PHP ones. Any help would be great.

```
application: mywebsiteapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: assets/index.html
  upload: assets/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: assets


- url: /php
  script: zoom.php
```

[image]

I would like to use something like this but it does not work?

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: assets/index.html
  upload: assets/index.html

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|xml|html))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|xml|html)$
  application_readable: true

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `static_dir` for `/` handler is going to matching all requests and swallow everything, and only serves files.

Use explicit static handlers for your js/css/img directories and then have 
explicit script handlers for save.php and zoom.php.

Comment: Thanks Tim I have tried lots of different ways of doing this, I have added my favorite to the original question but I can't get any to work?

Comment: What does your file heirarchy now look like. Based on your desired setup your php files need to in the root directory and not in /assets/php/

Comment: my file heirarchy is the same a above

Comment: ok, but the handler you added to your question expects it in the the root level.

Comment: So I have change it to script: php\1

Comment: only if you move the php folder up and out of assets.  I suggest you re-read the docs on defining handlers and the paths for static handlers.